# How do I fix this algorithm to generate branching and converging path?

Tags: algorithm, godot

I'm trying to specify an input of nodes per layer, such as **[1,2,5,3,1]** and generate connected nodes in a directed graph [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKOxB.png). Each node has a **next** array and a **prev** array. I keep messing up something in my loop to do this and I could use some guidance. Here's the gist of the pseudocode:

```
var node_layers = [1,2,5,3,1]
var prev_nodes = [start_node]
for i in range(1, len(node_layers)):
    var new_nodes = []
    for j in range(node_layers[i]):
        var new_node = Node()
        new_nodes.append(new_node)
        # connect the appropriate previous nodes to the current node
        new_node.prev = ??

    prev_nodes = new_nodes
```

Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
start = FloorNode.new(0)
current = start

var node_layers = [1,2,5,3,1]
var prev_nodes = [start]
for i in range(1, len(node_layers)):
    var new_nodes = []
    for j in range(node_layers[i]):
        var new_node = FloorNode.new(0)
        new_nodes.append(new_node)
        # connect the appropriate previous nodes to the current node
        new_node.prev = []
        var prev_nodes_per_node = max(1.0, 1.0 * node_layers[i]/node_layers[i-1])
        print("per node: ", prev_nodes_per_node)
        var relative_index = j * node_layers[i-1] / node_layers[i]
        print("j, relative index: ", j, ", ", relative_index)
        for k in range(ceili(relative_index-prev_nodes_per_node/2), floori(relative_index+prev_nodes_per_node/2) + 1):
            if k >= 0 and k < len(prev_nodes):
                print("Connect ", i-1, "[", k, "] to ", i, "[", j, "]")
                FloorNode.link(prev_nodes[k], new_node)

    prev_nodes = new_nodes
```

It generates a graph [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnTiF.png) which isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@burkay's answer doesn't work as intended for pairs like (1, 4) and (4, 4).

It seems you should use:

```
 let threshold = 0.5/Math.min(m, n);
```

I.e. half the distance between two nodes on the line with fewer nodes.

I translated it in a more "traditional" idiom.

```js
function getArcs(n, m) {
    var a = new Array(n);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i] = (i+0.5) / n;
    }

    var b = new Array(m);
    for (i=0; i<m; i++) {
        b[i] = (i+0.5) / m;
    }

    var th = 0.5 / Math.min(n, m);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
            if (Math.abs(a[i] - b[j]) <= th) {
                console.log(`${i} -> ${j}`);
            }
        }
    }
}

getArcs(4, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment:) Unfortunately this function does not give the correct links for m=3, n=5. It gives 0 -> 0, 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3 and 2 -> 4 but misses 1 -> 1 and 1 -> 3. Could you also fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 5 (m) nodes on a row and 3 (n) nodes on the following row. Below are the steps to get which node connects to which with a picture to illustrate the approach:

1. Calculate the threshold value for deciding nodes are connected or not, which is `1/Math.max(m, n) = 1/5 = 0.2`.
2. Distribute the nodes evenly on the number line [0, 1] and find the projections of nodes to the line. For an even distribution, set a left and right padding of `1/2*m` for the first row and `1/2*n` for the second row.
3. If the difference between the projected points of two nodes from different rows is less than or equal to the threshold, they are connected.

[image]

Here is the javascript code:

```js
function getConnectedIndices(m, n) {
    let a = new Array(m).fill(0).map((x, i) => (i)/(m)+(1/2/m));
    let b = new Array(n).fill(0).map((x, i) => (i)/(n)+(1/2/n));

    let ab = a.map(x => b.map(y => Math.abs(x - y)));
    
    let threshold = 1/Math.max(m, n);
    
    return ab.map(x => x.map((y, i) => y <= threshold ? i : null).filter(x => x !== null));
}

let result = getConnectedIndices(3, 5);
result.forEach((x, i) => console.log(`Node ${i} in first row is connected to nodes (${x}) of the second row`));
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time for this writeup. This is great!